# Wrong date given from Date() object metthods

Tags: node.js, firebase, date, google-cloud-functions

When printing the `new Date()` object out I get the correct date `Wed Jul 14 2021 02:29:46 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)`, of course I have to adjust it for the timezone I need. But when I use methods to get the month, day and year the day and month values are wrong. I log out the output into the Firebase Functions logs. I tried the `getFullMonth()` and `getUTCMonth()` methods, but both give incorrect results. Why is it that the `Date()` object is giving correct results but the methods are not?

```
exports.checkDailyRewards = functions.https
    .onRequest(async (req, res) => {
      const userId: string = req.query.id!.toString();
      const userProfileRef = db.collection("users").doc(userId);

      const currentDateObj = new Date();
      const otherDate = Date.now();

      console.log("other date: " + otherDate);

      console.log("current date object: " + currentDateObj);

      const year = String(currentDateObj.getFullYear());
      let month = String(currentDateObj.getMonth());
      let day = String(currentDateObj.getDay());

      console.log("month: " + currentDateObj.getMonth());
      console.log("day: " + currentDateObj.getDay());

      if (month.length == 1) {
        month = "0" + month;
      }

      if (day.length == 1) {
        day = "0" + day;
      }

      const currentDateStr = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

      console.log("currentDateStr: " + currentDateStr);

      const userDailyRewardsResult = await userProfileRef
          .collection("daily_rewards").doc(currentDateStr).get();

      if (userDailyRewardsResult.exists) {
        console.log("reward already received");
        res.status(200).send({dailyRewardReceived: "false"});
      } else {
        console.log("reward not received today");
        const rewardData = {
          experience: "5",
          currency: "5",
        };

        userProfileRef.collection("daily_rewards")
            .doc(currentDateStr)
            .set(rewardData);

        res.status(200).send({
          dailyRewardReceived: "true",
          rewardData,
        });
      }
    });
```

As shown in the screenshot, the `month: 6` and `day: 3` values are wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript [getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth#return_value) and [getUtcMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth) functions return a value ranging 0-11. This means you'll need to add 1 to the value returned to get the month of the year in the range 1-12.

Additionally, you're using the [getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) function, which returns the day of the week from 0-6. What you actually want is [getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) which returns the date of the month between 1-31.